# Picker Selection "nil" is Invalid and doesn't have a Tag

Tags: swiftui, ios16

I have an app that stores transaction data with a category classification. The category names may be selected from a pool of enclosed names or added through text entry. The problem that I am having is with the selection of categories from pool of names.

The structure GetCategory is designed to select a transaction category. For example, buying some items at the grocery store might be categorized under a food category.
The return value of this struct is to return the category name string.

Category selection is producing a warning message:

The transaction category selection process is producing the error **Picker: the selection "nil" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results.**

I have tried the selection process with and without a tag and also with and without an optional, but don't seem to be getting any closer to resolving this warning and error.

The category-in-use flag *catInuse* is set true when selected.

```
struct GetCategory: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories

    @Binding var entryCat: CatModel?

    var categoryList: [CatModel] {
        return categories.catItem.filter(\.catInUse)
    }

    var body: some View {

        ForEach(categoryList) { list in
            Text(list.catName)
        }

        Section(header: Text("Select Category")) {
            Picker("", selection: $entryCat) {

                ForEach(categoryList) { category in
                    Text(category.catName)
                        .tag(Optional(category.id))
                }
            }.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        }
        if let gotName = entryCat {
            Text("Selected Category is \(gotName.catName)")
                .padding(.top, 15)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Picker selection "0" is invalid and does not have an associated tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75431893/picker-selection-0-is-invalid-and-does-not-have-an-associated-tag)

Comment: Each Picker item must have an associated tag. If you want a "Nothing selected" state then you have to add a menu item for `Nothing selected` this can display also an empty string. If not you have to assign a default item to the `entryCat` property.

Comment: I don't want a nothing selected menu item

Comment: Hi @workingDog: Thanks for the help. GetCategory() works great as you created it without any warnings, but if I add the line if category.catInUse  around text line I get the console warning “Picker: the selection "CatModel(catNum:, catName: "Lodging", catTotal:, catBudget:, catPix:, catInUse: false, catCustom:)" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results.” Lodging category is the first of 14 available categories for use in the app but in this instance the user did not select the Lodging category.

Comment: *I don't want a nothing selected menu item*. The picker **must** display something if nothing is selected, at least an empty string which is technically an empty menu item. The alternative – as I said –  is to assign a default value or to hide the picker. So unlike the `selection` of a `List` the `entryCat` property  is supposed to be non-optional.

Comment: Hi @vadian. The app is designed so that if there are no categories selected from the pool of category names a message will appear indicating that categories need to be selected and preventing transaction entry. Once a group of working categories is selected this group will appear during transaction entry in a dropdown list. The warning I have been seeing in the console occurs when the first category in the large pool hasn’t been selected and is not appearing among the working categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reflextion, here is another approach that uses `entryCat: CatModel?` and test it is
not `nil` before displaying the `Picker`. This way the option of `nil` selection is
not possible.

The code below is just some example code that works for me, ie it does not produce the warnings. You need to ajust the
code to suit your needs.

```
struct CatModel:  Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var catNum: Int         // used by setup categories
    var catName: String     // category name
    var catTotal: Double    // category total
    var catBudget: Double   // category budget
    var catPix: String      // sf symbol
    var catInUse: Bool      // catInUse: true = category in use
    var catCustom: Bool     // true = custom category (can be deleted)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var categories = Categories()
    @State var entryCat: CatModel? // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Text("Selected is \(entryCat?.catName ?? "no selection")") // <-- here for testing
            GetCategory(entryCat: $entryCat)
                .environmentObject(categories)
            
            // for testing, change some catInUse to true
            Button("click to test") {
                // change the first false catInUse to true
                if let first = categories.catItem.firstIndex(where: {!$0.catInUse}) {
                    categories.catItem[first].catInUse = true
                    entryCat = categories.catItem[first]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Categories: ObservableObject {

    // this is for testing purpose
    @Published var catItem = [
        CatModel(catNum: 0, catName: "Cat A", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "a.circle", catInUse: false, catCustom: true),
        CatModel(catNum: 1, catName: "Cat B", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "b.circle", catInUse: true, catCustom: true),
        CatModel(catNum: 2, catName: "Cat C", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "c.circle", catInUse: true, catCustom: true)
        //..... more  CatModel
    ]
    
    //..... more code
}

struct GetCategory: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories
    
    @Binding var entryCat: CatModel? // <-- here

    var categoryList: [CatModel] {
        categories.catItem.filter(\.catInUse)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section(header: Text("Select Category")) {
                if entryCat != nil  {  // <-- here
                    Picker("", selection: $entryCat) {
                        ForEach(categoryList) { category in
                            Text(category.catName).tag(category as CatModel?) // <-- here, needed
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                } else {
                    Text("No selections available").foregroundColor(.red) // <-- here is entryCat == nil
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // <-- try to make entryCat not nil, for testing if needed
            if entryCat == nil  {
                if let theEntryCat = categoryList.first {
                    entryCat = theEntryCat
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you are doing with the class Categories. Each entry has catName, catTotal, catBudget, catPix, catInUse, and catCustom. Am I to add all of these to the publisher? In ContentView @State entryCat is showing the error “Missing arguments for parameters catTotal, catBudget, etc. The difference between your code and mine is in the class.

Comment: updated my answer with another approach that uses `CatModel?`. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a `Divider` `tag`ged with, in your case, `CatModel?(nil)` as the last item in `Picker`. Since `Divider`s in menus are not rendered if they're the last item it will silence your warning and it will not be selectable:

```swift
Divider().tag(CatModel?(nil))
```

As an aside, in order to select a default value with data that is fetched from elsewhere, assign it within an `.onAppear(perform:)` on `Picker`:

```swift
.onAppear {
  if self.entryCat == nil {
    self.entryCat = self.categoryList.first
  }
}
```